# Cannot Play DVDs on Linux Mint

Tags: dvd

I recently updated my operating system to Linux Mint and everything is running fine, except my DVD/CD drive will not read DVDs. CDs are fine but DVDs will not run. Do you have any advice of what I can do?

Comment: What software are you using to read DVDs, and what is it's output?

Comment: Are these movie DVDs or data DVDs? For the former, do you have `libdvdcss` installed?

Comment: What player are you using? Launch the player from a terminal and you should be able to watch any errors which are produced in stdout. Have you got all the necessary codecs installed?

Comment: The movies are DVD's not data DVD's. I'm using VLC player. The problem is that the computer does not recognize a dvd when it is the dvd player. I loaded libdvdcss but it says that libdvdcss has no installation candidate. I'm not sure I have all of the necessary codecs installed. How do I find out what I need?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly missing Codecs that allow the decryption of DVD content.  This is a well known issue and the libraries required aren't included with most distros by default because of the potential legal implications.  Full details here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with vlc media player On Linux Mint playing a movie DVD. It would just stop at the start. By accident more then by plan, I used the 'Media Player' which asked for additional software to run the dvd. After it downloaded and installed what it required, it was able to play the dvd. On switching back to vlc it worked fine.